# InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy error with angular material lazy loading problem

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading

i have two modules in my angular 9 app
only one module uses angular material.
so my app.module.ts don't load it, i use lazy loading
but when i run the app it shows an error

> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(t)[InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy -> InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy -> InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy -> InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy!

some one help please.

Comment: I believe this is related to https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19335, unfortunately the bug is not getting a lot of traction.

Comment: i think material modules should be loaded on the first instance

Answer (score 7):

What removed the error for me, was including `MatDialogModule` and `MatMenuModule` in the `AppModule`, which isn't lazy-loaded:

```js
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
```

Then finally the `mat-menu` worked again!

#### Why does this work?

My guess is that some `@angular/material` components have some implicit dependencies on those 2 specific modules. Hopefully they fix it in the future, so you don't need this...

Comment: why this solved the issue?

Comment: @pixparker updated answer ^

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same situation. What solves me is to import `MatAutocompleteModule` in `app.module.ts` even you need it in submodules.

**app.module.ts**

```
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';


imports: [
  MatAutocompleteModule,
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer which solved the problem for me too. I wonder if you figured out why it is also needed in app.module.ts ?

Answer (score 3):

The below solution works for me:

*You must have to import this module at the root level instead of the module based, earlier I imported it at the module level.*

Import below three modules in your app.module.ts or shared module which you shared across the application

- **MatInputModule**
- **MatAutocompleteModule**
- **MatSelectModule**

import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';

import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a routing error. In the parent path using lazy loading, I have placed the bookmarks component. In the morning I also referred to the same component with tabs.

Parent:

```js
{
    path: MyProfileRoutesEnum.settings,
    data: {[MY_DATA_PARAM]: true},
    component: MySettingsContainerComponent, // need to delete this
    loadChildren: () => import('./my-settings/my-settings.module').then((m) => m.MySettingsModule),
},
```

Child:

```js
{
    path: `:${TAB_PARAM}`,
    component: MySettingsContainerComponent,
},
```

Must be parent:

```js
{
    path: MyProfileRoutesEnum.settings,
    data: {[MY_DATA_PARAM]: true},
    loadChildren: () => import('./my-settings/my-settings.module').then((m) => m.MySettingsModule),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally placed a route in app.routing that refers to the lazily loaded component.

So I had the path in app.module added as

```
{path: 'worksheet-list', component: WorksheetListComponent},
```

Instead of keeping the path inside the lazy module